# Selenium - Firefox webdriver will only take partial screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

From what I've read the following code:

```
    File s = ((TakesScreenshot)driver_).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(s,new File("C:\\scr.png"));
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Should take a full page screenshot. But in my case it will only take the screenshot of whatever is currently visible in the browser window. Is this the expected behaviour or did something go wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expected behavior from firefox.
If you want to take full page screenshot you can use something like this to zoom out the whole contents to visible area

```
executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver.getDriver();
executor.executeScript(
         "document.body.style.zoom=
            (top.window.screen.height-70)/
            Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

It will try to bring all the content to visible area, although you can still miss some content from the very bottom area.